# MVC manually serializing complex object or model binding

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

One of the largest issues I run into in MVC is when I attach a complex property (view model) to my model to use on a form.  For example, I have a model called Customer.cs.  This Customer has ( for simplicity sake ) 1 order at any time.  So I give him a property of Customer.Order.  The Customer has many other properties defining him as a unique customer.  The Order property has a set of unique properties itself.  So I’m rolling along, building my Controller, other model values, and finally I start working out my View details.
I start by defining the Form itself.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Customer", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "customerForm" })
```

This form declaration basically tells the View that when a user clicks Submit, everything within this form should be serialized and sent to the Controller. 
First, I create a view for my main model, Customer.cshtml.  It takes in a Customer.cs model.

I create a View specifically for this complex object I’ve created called Order.cshtml.  It takes in an Order.cs model (so I can reuse it later on other parent models, such as Invoice because I’m smart and think ahead.)  So I’ve written all of this javascript and view logic that depends on the view being independent and reusable with other models.  My textboxfor declarations look like so:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m. OrderDate)
```

When I go to click Submit, the first thing I notice is that none of the values from the Order object are posted back.  So I sit there and debug and it takes a while but I finally figure out that this will not work this way.  Unless there’s a way to serialize the view model separately, then attach it to the parent model, even then you’d have to write a bunch of Javascript to manually override the default form submission process, along with any other model submits you may be making for client-side field validation.
I think there should be an easier way to handle this.  I know a way around this issue, but it’s not pretty.  You ‘could’ create the view for Order.cs to take in a Customer.cs model instead.  Then, use textboxfor declarations like so:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Order.OrderDate)
```

To define all of the properties on the View.  This will work with the default binding and all is well.  Except, what about the code I’ve already written in JavaScript?  I’d have to go through and append “Order_” to all of the references to ID’s laid out on the form.  Also, this does not move easily between models now, I’d have to recreate this View each time I create a new model that uses the Order object, since it now takes in the Customer.cs model.  I’d also have to rewrite the javascript, or come up with some fancy way to pass in a prefix (ViewData).  This doesn’t seem correct.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you create an interface for all view models that use Order:

```
interface IWithOrder
{
    Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Use this interface in your common Order view:

```
@model Project.ViewModels.IWithOrder
...
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Order.OrderDate, new { Id = "OrderDate" })
```

In case of Customer you can create Customer view model, which derive from IWithOrder:

```
public class CustomerViewModel : IWithOrder
{
    public Order Order { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Now you are able to reuse `Order` view, but your view models needs to derive from IWithOrder.

You can also set id of html elements in `htmlAttributes` parameter of [`TextBoxFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Object%29")if you don't want to append `Order_` in js references.

Comment: This is a solution, I will mark as answer until there is a better one.  I have done this, but the issue with this is the methods that will be needed to work with Orders, they're going to be the same every time but I'm still going to have to stub them out in the interface, to turn around and copy/paste in each model.  The id can be set, that is true. I need some time to think about this.  Thanks.

Comment: I went ahead and implemented something very similar, and I have to say, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks so much, using your method allows me to also define the Data Annotations (I didn't want to lose when using an interface) as well as define a solid implementation of the methods used to calculate fields. That's exactly why I didn't resort to an interface in the first place, was the fear of losing those implementations.